# Remove template text on regexp_replace in Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I am trying to remove template text like &#x; or &#xx; or &#xxx; from long string

Note: x / xx / xxx - is number, The length of the number is unknown, The cell type is CLOB

for example:

```
SELECT 'H&#39;ello wor&#177;ld' FROM dual
```

A desirable result:

```
Hello world
```

I know that **regexp_replace** should be used, But how do you use this function to remove this text?

Comment: As long as you know the function you need please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'&&#\d+;')       
  FROM t
```

where

- **`&`** is put twice to provide escaping for the substitution character
- **`\d`** represents digits and the following **`+`** provides the multiple occurrences of them
- ending the pattern with **`;`**

or just use a single ampersand (**`'&#\d+;'`**) for the pattern as in the case of <kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zmZHyVOm)</kbd> , since an ampersand has a special meaning for Oracle, a usage is a bit problematic.

Comment: Can you retry just like within the demo @user19970094

Comment: @user19970094 Can you explain it on the demo playground of which's address I've shared within the last edit of the answer, and provide the created link here(as a comment).

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted to remove the entities because you don't know how to replace them by their character values, here is a solution:

```
UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE( xmlquery( 'the_double_quoted_original_string' RETURNING content).getStringVal() )
```

In other words, the original `'H&#39;ello wor&#177;ld'` should be passed to XMLQUERY as `'"H&#39;ello wor&#177;ld"'`.

And the result will be 'H'ello wo±ld'